# Create a PPT using C# without having to kill a running powerpnt process

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I've been trying to create a PPT with C# using something like the code below.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application pptApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
```

The problem is, if there's another powerpnt process running, the line of code above doesn't do anything (even when debugging it). The application just hangs infinitely.

Is there a way to be able to generate PPTs without having to kill an existing powerpnt process?

Comment: Are you running this on a desktop or from a service or on a server. If one of the latter two, Interop is a bad idea. If it's a PPTX (not a PPT), then you can use one of the OpenXML tools (like the OpenXML SDK)

Comment: I'm running it from a desktop WPF application. Is Interop an obsolete library?

Comment: Are you saying that the `new` operation in your example never returns and just hangs? Or that your application hangs for some other reason?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that running the Interop capability on anything other than an interactive desktop is a really bad idea. A WPF app runs in an interactive desktop

Comment: Interop is easy ... but it has many down sides.  Including the problem you're experiencing.  One alternative is OpenXml: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-presentation-slides

Answer (score 2):

With [Aspose.Slides for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/net/), you don't need to install PowerPoint to generate presentations with a single line of code:

```cs
using (Presentation presentation = new Presentation())
{
    // Add content to the presentation here
    // ...
    presentation.Save("output.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx); // You can choose many other formats
}
```

Also, you can see your results by using Online Viewer [here](https://products.aspose.app/slides/viewer).

I work at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

In NET Framework you can hook into the "Running Object Table" (ROT) and get a running Powerpoint instance using InteropServices.Marshal.
Then you can work with the running instance. If it is not running you can start it.

```
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        using PowerPointApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application;

        PowerPointApp ppApp = null;
        try
        {
            var ppType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PowerPoint.Application");
            var ppRaw  = Marshal.GetActiveObject("PowerPoint.Application");
            ppApp  = ppRaw as PowerPointApp;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        if (ppApp == null)
        {

            ppApp = new PowerPointApp();
        }
```

`Marshal.GetActiveObject` is not available in .NET Core and current .NET 5/6